# Use tablesorter to filter selected items in options list chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter, jquery-chosen

I have table that is filtered with the help of Tablesorter. Each column have a search box on he top. In one of the columns I have an options list that is based on the Chosen JavaScript. I like to be able to filter this column based on what have been selected in the option list. I have tried using the textExtraction function triggering on the span tag that surrounds the selected item but I can't get it to work. Any suggestions are welcome.

I have a setup in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hH8KM/1/)

```
<body>
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="title" data-placeholder="">Title</th>
            <th class="tags" data-placeholder="">Tags</th>
            <th class="date" data-placeholder="">Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Fish</td>
            <td>
                <select data-placeholder="Choose Tags" class="chosen-select" multiple>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Option1">Sweden</option>
                    <option value="Option2">Norway</option>
                    <option value="Option3">Finland</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>2012-12-03</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Boat</td>
            <td>
                <select data-placeholder="Choose Tags" class="chosen-select" multiple>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Option1">Sweden</option>
                    <option value="Option2">Norway</option>
                    <option value="Option3">Finland</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>2012-12-15</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("table").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    textExtraction: {
        1: function (node, table, cellIndex) {
            return $(node).find("span").text();
        }
    },
    widthFixed: true,
    widgets: ["zebra", "filter"],
    widgetOptions: {
        filter_childRows: false,
        filter_columnFilters: true,
        filter_cssFilter: 'tablesorter-filter',
        filter_functions: null,
        filter_hideFilters: false,
        filter_ignoreCase: true,
        filter_reset: 'button.reset',
        filter_searchDelay: 300,
        filter_startsWith: false,
        filter_useParsedData: false

    }

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well there are just a few things missing to make it all work.

First, here is an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hH8KM/3/).

To start, the value of the option should match the text, or you can modify the parser to instead find the selected options and get their text.

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose Tags" class="chosen-select" multiple>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
    <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
    <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
</select>
```

Next, include a parser to get the selected options and also update the table cache:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "select",
    is: function () {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s, table, cell) {
        // since the select can get multiple results in an array,
        // we combine all the values using join(',')
        return ($(cell).find('select').val() || []).join(',') || s;
    },
    type: "text"
});

// this flag prevents the updateCell event from being spammed
// it happens when you modify input text and hit enter
var alreadyUpdating = false;
$('table').find('tbody').on('change', 'select', function (e) {
    if (!alreadyUpdating) {
        var $tar = $(e.target),
            $table = $tar.closest('table');
        alreadyUpdating = true;
        $table.trigger('updateCell', [$tar.closest('td')]);
        setTimeout(function () {
            alreadyUpdating = false;
        }, 10);
    }
});
```

Now, make sure the header option is set (or add a "sorter-select" class to the `th`):

```
$("table").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    headers: {
        1: {
            sorter: 'select'
        }
    },
    // ....
 });
```

Lastly, set the header class name to only look for parsed data for that column (`filter-parsed`); the `data-value` was added to show that initial filters can also be set. This is also where the `sorter-select` class name could have been added instead of adding a `headers` option.

```
<th class="tags filter-parsed" data-value="sweden" data-placeholder="">Tags</th>
```

And all done!

Comment: Thank you that works great! I took we a while to figure out the code. Or rather I have manged to format part but I'm still working on the alreadyUpdating part. For anyone else struggling with the format part please check [link] http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers.html